# Autowiring and Dependency Injection

Tags: symfony

How Request like object are passed in action of controller. Is it some sort of autowiring?

```
class DefaultController {
  public function createAction(Request $request){

  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use this anymore, it's deprecated. Instead use the `request_stack` service and get the current request from that stack.

Comment: @Aitch The OP might use the 2.3 LTS version, which has no support for the new `request_stack` service. But in general yes, that's a good tip :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code explains how the request object is passed to a controller method:

https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/blob/master/Controller/ControllerResolver.php#L115